# Does anyone know how to add the MX Master to the Logi Options program?

Tags: macos, terminal, bluetooth

I can't seem to make sense of adding the MX Master to the Logi Options app. It is showing up in the Logi Bolt app, but it's not making the transition over.

I have tried a few things:

- Redownloaded both apps
- Killed the Logi daemon in activity and in the terminal
- Updated macOS

[image: Screenshot of the Logi Bolt app showing the MX Master recognized and the Logi Options not having recognized the MX Master]

Comment: Why aren't you just adding the BT device (mouse) to MX Master directly? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: When I click on the buttons in the top it opens the bottom

Comment: And if you click "Add new device"?